# What is the runtime complexity if one-fourth (quarter) of the problem is eliminated?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I tried to solve the following problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix-ii/). I solved it by divide and conquer technique, and eliminated one-fourth of the problem set each time. For details please see the code. It did work.

However, I am having a hard time coming up with run-time complexity for this (I know if the problem is divided in half its log N to the base of 2). I did see "discussion" in the leetcode for divide and conquer approach, even though I am glad someone solved with a similar approach I couldn't understand their discussion w.r.t run time complexity. Incidentally, do note that someone came up with an elegant O(m+n) solution - but am not sure which is superior with regard to run time complexity (I ran both algorithms in leetcode - it did say divide and conquer approach ran faster i think).

**Question:**

How can I determine the runtime complexity for this? This will help with my interview preparation.

> **Example problem description:**
>
> Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value in an m x n
>   matrix. This matrix has the following properties:
>
> 1. Integers in each row are sorted in ascending from left to right.
> 2. Integers in each column are sorted in ascending from top to bottom.

**Algorithm approach - (as requested from the comments):**

1. Basically say, if the matrix is of m X n. I find the center element.
2. If the center element is the target element, I will simply return true.
3. Else if the target element is greater than the center element, then I eliminate the top left quarter (as element won't be there in that section), and try to find it in the other three quarters.

*Note*: even though its 3 quarters, I make only 2 recursive calls. The first one for one of the quarters and the second recursive call combines 2 quarters.

4. Else I eliminate bottom right quarter and do the same (similar to #3).

   ```
   public class SearchIn2DArray_II_DivideAndConquer {

   public static boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {
       if (null == matrix || matrix.length == 0 || matrix[0].length == 0) {
           return false;
       }
       return searchMatrix(matrix, target, 0, 0, matrix.length - 1, matrix[0].length - 1);
   }

   private static boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target, int rowStart, int columnStart, int rowEnd, int columnEnd) {
       if (rowStart < 0 || rowStart >= matrix.length
               || columnStart < 0 || columnStart >= matrix[0].length
               || rowEnd < 0 || rowEnd >= matrix.length
               || columnEnd < 0 || columnEnd >= matrix[0].length
               || rowStart > rowEnd
               || columnStart > columnEnd) {
           return false;
       }
       if (rowStart == rowEnd && columnStart == columnEnd) {
           return target == matrix[rowStart][columnStart];
       }
       int m = (rowEnd - rowStart) + 1;
       int n = (columnEnd - columnStart) + 1;
       int length = m * n;
       int center = length / 2;
       int r = center / n;
       int c = center % n;
       int centerRow = rowStart + r;
       int centerColumn = columnStart + c;
       System.out.println(rowStart + " " + columnStart + " " + rowEnd + " " + columnEnd + " ");
       System.out.println(m + " " + n + " " + r + " " + c + " ");
       System.out.println(centerRow + " " + centerColumn);
       if (matrix[centerRow][centerColumn] == target) {
           return true;
       }
       if (target > matrix[centerRow][centerColumn]) {
           return searchMatrix(matrix, target, rowStart, centerColumn + 1, centerRow, columnEnd)
                   || searchMatrix(matrix, target, centerRow + 1, columnStart, rowEnd, columnEnd);

       }
       return searchMatrix(matrix, target, centerRow, columnStart, rowEnd, centerColumn - 1)
               || searchMatrix(matrix, target, rowStart, columnStart, centerRow - 1, columnEnd);
   }
   ```

   }

Corresponding test case (to run the method):

```
 @Test
    public void searchMatrix() {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        final String jsonString = "[[1,2,3,4,5]]";
        int[][] matrix = gson.fromJson(jsonString, int[][].class);
        Assert.assertTrue(SearchIn2DArray_II_DivideAndConquer.searchMatrix(matrix, 1));
    }
```

Comment: *"For details please see the code."* Since you are the one who understands the high-level details of your solution, it's probably going to be easier for you to put those into words, than it is for those reading your question to work it out by reading your code (which is not as self-explanatory as you might imagine). There are also lots of us and only one of you, so it's a lot less work in total if you edit the question to describe, in high-level terms, how your algorithm works. If this is for interview practice, then explaining an idea in high-level terms is definitely worth practicing.

Comment: Sure, will add details w.r.t algorithm

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. *"...and try to find it in other three quarters"* - does this mean three recursive calls on those three quarters? In your code I only see `return` statements which make two recursive calls.

Comment: But the second recursive call combines two quarters. i.e; 2 recursive calls (1 quarter + 2 quarters).

Comment: I see. That gives a different recurrence relation than if you had three recursive calls, though. I'll have a think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the shapes of the subproblems, the recurrence relation for your problem in the worst case (where N = m*n) is:

```
T(N) = T(N/2) + T(N/4) + O(1)
```

As we expand the terms, all of the subproblem sizes are going to be N/2<sup>x</sup>.  Let's call *x* the "level" of the subproblem.  There will be *log<sub>2</sub> N* levels of calls altogether before we get to constant size.

The total work is proportional to the total number of calls, so if we can figure out how many calls there are at each level, we can add them up to get the total.

From the recurrence relation, we can see that each call at level *x* produces one at each of the next two levels.  The number of calls at level *x*, therefore, equals the number of calls at the previous 2 levels.  The number of calls at level 0 is 1, so the counts for each level follow the Fibonacci sequence:

```
Level:    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
calls:    1    1    2    3    5    8   13
  sum:    1    2    4    7   12   20   33
```

Since the sum of the first n fibonacci numbers (sum[F<sub>1</sub>...F<sub>n</sub>]) is just F<sub>n+2</sub>-1, the sum of the calls at each level grows at the same exponential rate.  From Binet's formula, this is ~ 1.618.

So...

The total cost of your method is O(1.618^log_2(N)), which is about O(N<sup>0.7</sup>)

For square matrices, the (m+n) method is O(N<sup>0.5</sup>), which is better than yours.

Comment: Definitely better to use O(m+n) for square matrices or those of any fixed aspect ratio. However, with m > n, if m > n^2 it's more competitive and if m > n^3 the divide and conquer method should be asymptotically faster.

Comment: Right, although in those cases just iterating through the short side with binary search on the long side gives O(short*log(long)), which is much better

Comment: Hmm, that can't be true, though. The divide and conquer approach reduces the size of the problem by at least as much at every comparison as iterating with binary search; it in effect runs multiple binary searches simultaneously. In particular if you choose the shorter dimension to be reduced in size every time (call it n) then within log(n) levels you're cutting the problem in half every time and only adding one subproblem at every level, so this slightly modified approach would also be O(short*log(long)).

Comment: Yes, that's true.  My analysis ignored the matrix aspect ratio.  If you specifically cut the short side every time then worst case comes out better, because there are at most log_2(N)/2 levels that spawn 2 recursive calls, and after that it does a binary search.